# Toggle "tabbable" - bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve something that I'm relatively sure has been done several times before, however I can't seem to find any documetation on it.

I'm using the responsive bootstrap for this, and the affected functionality revolves around the "tabbable" component. (see below)

```
<div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
         <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
         <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is a functionality that hides the content of the tab if it is already active. (in the example above, clicking the active `< a >` should remove the `"active"` class from both the button itself and the related div (`#tab1`) in a way that poses no threat for tabbable functionality)

I would think that there is a very simple solution to this, being new to bootstrap however, I haven't been able to locate it yet and don't want to dig my own grave using some obsure javascript solution.

Edit: After a comment I wanted to clarify my query even more. I want no tabs at all shown if i click on the button related to the div that is in in its active state, In other words, I want the click to work the same way .toggle works in jquery, like a flipswitch.

Any ideas/input greatly appriciated!

Comment: The Bootstrap tabs should work as you describe with the code above. When you click on Tab2 `active` is removed from Tab1 and Tab1 content, and `active` is added to Tab2 and Tab2 content. Is it not working this way for you?

Comment: Skelly: That is exactly how it works, I might have described it a bit confusing: but if I were to click the a related to Tab2 twice I want it to show, and then hide again on the second click, returning to a state where no tab is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this using just HTML markup and data attributes. If can be acheived easily with a little JavaScript (not too obscure!)..

```
$('[data-toggle=tab]').click(function(){
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
    $($(this).attr("href")).toggleClass('active');
  }
})
```

<kbd>[**Bootply Demo**](http://bootply.com/61835)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a heap Skelly, it works as intended, this is absolutley a viable option as long as this isn't already built into some obscure component already available in bootstrap!

Comment: Consider rewriting `$($(this).attr("href")).` to `$(this.href).` - if [nothing else](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element) to enhance readability :)